Is there a way to convert a getline string into a numerical value to be able to use it in a switch statement?
int main(){
    std::string ID;

    std::cout << "*****Welcome to miniclean property managers*****\n";
    std::cout << "Please enter your airBnB's address: ";

    std::getline(std::cin, ID); 
    
    switch(ID){

    }
    return 0;
}

This is just a chunk of the code
What im trying to do is be able to insert an address into the getline statement, then be able to use that to give a code using the switch statement.
So is there a way I can do that? or convert the string into a numerical value and use that in the switch statement?
Ive tried converting it to int or even char values, but im really not getting anywhere lol. Im still newish to c++ so help would be appreciated. Thanks!

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

The usual way would be to use the stream’s converter: int ID; std::cin >> ID;.

std::cout << "Please enter your airBnB's address: ";  I wouldn't expect this to be a number. Instead I expect it to be a postal address. Maybe this is not the question you want to ask?

Can you output a numbered list of known addresses, so that a number being input can cleanly and intuitively identify one? Then do as Pete Becker suggested.

Since you know the std::strings or you expect specific std::strings, why not consider an std::hash? See compile-time std::string hashing.

this is probably what you want:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string ID;

    std::cout << "*****Welcome to miniclean property managers*****\n";
    std::cout << "Please enter your airBnB's address: ";

    ID = "5"; // Replace with std::getline(std::cin, ID); 
    
    switch(std::stoi(ID)){

        default: std::cout << "ID = " << std::stoi(ID) << std::endl;

    }
    return 0;
}

but I think it might be better to just define the ID as int.
